# I get the exception "Apache Camel Cannot acquire lock within xxx millis. Will skip the file"

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, filezilla

I got the execption while uploading a 0-KB .csv file to my FTP server using [FileZilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla). I am using Apache Camel to route the file and process it.

But while doing so, I am getting a warning "Apache Camel Cannot acquire lock within xxx millis. Will skip the file".

`org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.strategy.SftpChangedExclusiveReadLockStrategy Cannot acquire read lock within 20000 millis. Will skip the file: RemoteFile[filename.csv]`

Because of this, the file is not getting routed to my application and I am not able to process the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty file of 0 bytes is regarded as a file that are in-process of being updated. However there is an option on the FTP component where you can set the threshold to 0 bytes as OK to use. See the option `readLockMinLength` at the FTP docs at: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html